# How to get Intuit Data Services (IDS) beta features?

Tags: api, intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online, devkit

I'm trying to use `Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.VendorCredit` entity which is marked as limited beta feature [here](https://ipp.developer.intuit.com/0010_Intuit_Partner_Platform/0050_Data_Services/0400_QuickBooks_Online/0500_Supported_Entities_and_Operations). When I try to add its instance using development environment credentials I get "Internal server error" from IDS server.

So, my questions are:

1. Is this feature available for developers at all?
2. If YES then how can I get it?
3. If NO then is there any alternative solution?

I'll appreciate for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The entity is marked as beta which means use at your own risk as it is not currently supported in version 2 of the Quickbooks API. It will be available in the v3 QuickBooks API and fully supported but it is not out yet. You can get more information about the v3 QuickBooks API here at our next webinar.

http://ippblog.intuit.com/blog/2013/02/registration-for-ipp-quickbooks-api-v3-webinar-.html

There is not an alternative, but if want you can try using this XML Request to add a VendorCredit.

```xml
<Add RequestId="f262775d403d432e9b0173d3fd03036f" xmlns="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2 ./RestDataFilter.xsd">
    <ExternalRealmId>181967844</ExternalRealmId>
    <VendorCredit>
        <Header>
            <DocNumber>90001</DocNumber>
            <TxnDate>2011-01-20</TxnDate>
            <Note>New vendor</Note>
            <Status>Paid</Status>
            <VendorId idDomain="QB">263</VendorId>
            <VendorName>General Motors</VendorName>
            <BillEmail>jenW@foobar.com</BillEmail>
            <TotalAmt>200.0</TotalAmt>
            <PayerId idDomain="QB">263</PayerId>
            <PayerName>General Motors</PayerName>
            <APAccountId idDomain="QB">12</APAccountId>
            <APAccountName>Accounts Payable</APAccountName>
        </Header>
        <Line>
            <Desc>new line</Desc>
            <ClassId idDomain="QB">12</ClassId>
            <ClassName>Tub Design</ClassName>
            <ReimbursableInfo>
                <CustomerId idDomain="QB">281</CustomerId>
                <CustomerName>Disney</CustomerName>
                <JobId idDomain="QB">282</JobId>
                <JobName>StoryCreation</JobName>
            </ReimbursableInfo>
            <BillableStatus>Billable</BillableStatus>
            <ItemId idDomain="QB">118</ItemId>
            <ItemName>labor used in assembly</ItemName>
            <ItemType>Service</ItemType>
            <UnitPrice>50.0</UnitPrice>
            <Qty>4.0</Qty>
            <UOMId idDomain="QB">38</UOMId>
            <UOMAbbrv>Volume by the liter</UOMAbbrv>
        </Line>
    </VendorCredit>
</Add>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Jarred. As I see from your sample you suggest to use QBD instead of QBO. I hope we'll get V3 QBO API public beta pretty soon, so I can avoid migration to QBD.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that it was QBO. If you want I can send you the beta documentation so you can use it in QBO. submit an IPP support ticket and ask for the docs, ill have someone provide it for you.

Comment: That would be great (I've created a ticket). So now it looks like the fault of my problem is incorrect using of API or I have to make some changes to enable API beta functionality? -- just can't figure it out from error message.